# eclipse cannot generate makefiles automatically

Tags: eclipse, makefile

My OS is Ubuntu12.04 64bit,and I download eclipse for c/c++ from this site:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/R/eclipse-cpp-juno-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
when I run the eclipse, I found the checkbox of "Generate Makefiles Automatically" if gray, but I want eclipse generate makefile automatically.
thanks for any help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of the type of project you selected when creating it. Don't choose a makefile project (you'll have to provide your own makefile in this case), but one of the other options.